# No reference to buttons created through array in actionListener()

Tags: java

```
public class buttonInitialization extends JFrame {

public JButton[] button;

public buttonInitialization() {
    setLayout(new FlowLayout());    

    JButton[] button = new JButton[2];

    button[0] = new JButton("");
    button[0].setText("dsadsa");
    button[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                button[0].setText("dsaadsdsa"); 
        }
```

I cannot access this `button[0]` in action listener. How can I do that???

Comment: It has to be declared final.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make `button` variable `final`.

```
final JButton[] button = new JButton[2];
```

That is a requirement because anonymous inner classes (like your `new ActionListener()`) can access outer class variables only if they are `final`.

**EDIT** I tried to compile and it works. Here it goes again:

```
final JButton[] button = new JButton[2];

button[0] = new JButton("");
button[0].setText("dsadsa");
button[0].addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            button[0].setText("dsaadsdsa"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: I tried it just now...bt i still cannot use this command with it..

button[0].setText("sdjshshd");

IT is saying unknown source as an error...

Comment: Don't use an array then. Define them independently and name them properly.

Comment: im making a game...i need 20 buttons...i have to make it with array...can you tell me why this is not wrking????

Comment: @AnkurGoyal it must work. You are doing something wrong. Check my updated answer. In your code you missed one closing bracket `}`.

Answer (score 0):

```
     public class buttonInitialization extends JFrame {

            public JButton[] button;

        public buttonInitialization() {
            setLayout(new FlowLayout());    

            JButton[] button = new JButton[2];

            button[0] = new JButton("");
            button[0].setText("dsadsa");
            for(int i = 0; i< button.length; ++i)
                 button[i].addActionListener(new MyActionListener(button[i]));
        }

        private class MyActionListener implements ActionListener
        {
           private JButton button;

           public MyActionListener(JButton button)
           {
               this.button = button;
           }
              @Override
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {

                            this.button.setText("dsaadsdsa"); 
                    }

        }
```

Comment: That's a really bad idea. This class should not be a `Listener`.

Comment: i agree but its just a quick fix? instread he could just create a private iner class that implements ActionListener

Comment: It's a quick fix, but a wrong fix. Each button should have its own `Listener` and not to share the whole class as a `Listener`. Also, he would have to do multiple conditions to determine which button to change. And last but not least, it's a source of memory leak.

Comment: is this better? just asking honestly, i dont have alot of programming experience.

Comment: Yes it is in case all buttons should perform the same on every action.

Comment: i had planned to assign a setActionCommand for each button with one ActionListener defined in an "event" class...n getting access to each button through getActionCommand()...in such a way, less memory leak...n less code of lines...